# Menu Indicator bar stuck to the 2 icon

Tags: html, css

I don't know why but I tried to add text boxes above the icons but it remains blocked at the 2nd icon.
I can press the 3rd icon and go back to the first one but when I press the second icon I cannot go back to the first one.
The same if I add text boxes.
It is always on the last text box that it remains blocked.
ps: sorry for my bad english (i'm french).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
:root {
    --clr: #222327;
  --new-color: #00a2ff;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: var(--clr);
}
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 350px;
}
.navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    Justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.navigation ul li a .icon {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: var(--clr);
}
.navigation ul li.active a .icon {
    transform: translateY(-32px);
}
.navigation ul li a .text {
    position: absolute;
    color: var(--clr);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}
.navigation ul li.active a .text {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-25px);
}
.indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #29fd53;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid var(--clr);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.indicator::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}
.indicator::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: -1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(1).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 0));
  background: #00a2ff; /*blue*/
  --new-color: #00a2ff;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(2).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 1));
  background: #ae00ff; /*purple*/
  --new-color: #ae00ff;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(3).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 2));
  background: #696563; /*grey*/
  --new-color: #696563;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(4).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 3));
  background: #ffe91f; /*yellow*/
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(5).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 4));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(6).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 5));
}




.navigation ul li.active a span menu { /*anim-opacity-start*/
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
  justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
  background: var(--new-color); /*blue*/
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-130px) translateX(calc(70px * 1));
}
.navigation ul li a span .menu { /*anim-opacity-end*/
    transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-135px) translateX(calc(70px * 1));
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Magic Menu Indicator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body
      <!DOCTYPE html>
  #1
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="list active">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="earth-outline"></ion-icon>
            <menu class="menu"></menu>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Navigateur</span>
                </a>
            </li>
      #2
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
            <menu class="menu"></menu>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
       #3
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="terminal-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Terminal</span>
                </a>
            </li>
       #4
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="image-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Photos</span>
                </a>
            </li>
       #5
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Paramètres</span>
                </a>
      </li>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
        function activelink(){
            list.forEach((item) =>
            item.classList.remove('active'));
            this.classList.add('active');
        }
        list.forEach((item) =>
        item.addEventListener('click',activelink));
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the size of the .icon. It covers other elements. The problem is solved if you add .navigation ul li a .icon {width: 100%; }.

[image: before][image: and after]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
:root {
    --clr: #222327;
  --new-color: #00a2ff;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: var(--clr);
}
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 350px;
}
.navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    Justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.navigation ul li a .icon {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: var(--clr);
}
.navigation ul li.active a .icon {
    transform: translateY(-32px);
}
.navigation ul li a .text {
    position: absolute;
    color: var(--clr);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}
.navigation ul li.active a .text {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-25px);
}
.indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #29fd53;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid var(--clr);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.indicator::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}
.indicator::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: -1px -10px 0 0 var(--clr);
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(1).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 0));
  background: #00a2ff; /*blue*/
  --new-color: #00a2ff;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(2).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 1));
  background: #ae00ff; /*purple*/
  --new-color: #ae00ff;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(3).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 2));
  background: #696563; /*grey*/
  --new-color: #696563;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(4).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 3));
  background: #ffe91f; /*yellow*/
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(5).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 4));
}

.navigation ul li:nth-child(6).active ~ .indicator {
    transform: translateX(calc(70px * 5));
}




.navigation ul li.active a span menu { /*anim-opacity-start*/
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
  justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
  background: var(--new-color); /*blue*/
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-130px) translateX(calc(70px * 1));
}
.navigation ul li a span .menu { /*anim-opacity-end*/
    transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-135px) translateX(calc(70px * 1));
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Magic Menu Indicator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body
      <!DOCTYPE html>
  #1
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li class="list active">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="earth-outline"></ion-icon>
            <menu class="menu"></menu>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Navigateur</span>
                </a>
            </li>
      #2
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
            <menu class="menu"></menu>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
       #3
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="terminal-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Terminal</span>
                </a>
            </li>
       #4
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="image-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Photos</span>
                </a>
            </li>
       #5
            <li class="list">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text">Paramètres</span>
                </a>
      </li>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
      
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
        function activelink(){
            list.forEach((item) =>
            item.classList.remove('active'));
            this.classList.add('active');
        }
        list.forEach((item) =>
        item.addEventListener('click',activelink));
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```